# htdocsに任意のファイルを置いてurlの最後尾を任意のファイル名に変えても表示されない

Tags: php, html

htdocsに任意のファイルを置いてurlの最後尾を任意のファイル名に変えても表示されないのはなぜでしょう？

ファイルに問題があるのでしょうか？

ファイルはhtml php両方で置いて 両方だめです

追記

実際に置いたディレクトリ : nfs://ip-ad/opt/lampp/htdocs/project

ファイル名 : pdo_form.php , pdo_form.html

アクセスしているURL : http://localhost:8080/project/pdo_form.html

http://localhost:8080/project/pdo_form.php

です

Comment: 実際に置いたディレクトリおよびファイル名とアクセスしているURLを追記してください

Comment: 実際に置いたディレクトリ : nfs://ip-ad/opt/lampp/htdocs/project　と、
アクセスしているURL : http://localhost:8080/project/pdo_form.html　は、どういう関係にあるのでしょうか？　

ip-ad/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectにアクセスする際のnfs://ip-ad/opt/lampp/htdocs/projectは、NFSプロトコルで、 http://localhost:8080/project/pdo_form.htmlは、HTTPプロトコルです。

同じように見えても、プロトコルが異なるのであれば別物です（同一である根拠が無いですから）